# When is a f:param actually sent?

Tags: jsf, parameters, jsf-1.2

I've got the following `h:commandButton`:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.myAction}" value="Send">
    <f:param name="myFlag" value="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

I want to gain access to `myFlag` insinde a [Validator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html), that's attached to another element with `f:validator`.

Unfortunately, when I want to retrieve the parameter through the [FacesContext](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html), I only get `null` returned.

Is it that the parameters are only sent once all validators have been invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:param>` inside `<h:commandButton>` is only supported since JSF 2.0, but you're using JSF 1.2. The `<f:param>` is then only supported in `<h:commandLink>`.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.myAction}" value="Send">
    <f:param name="myFlag" value="true" />
</h:commandLink>
```

There are alternatives, such as a `<h:inputHidden>` or `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` or `<f:attribute>` or in this case perhaps just plain `<input type="hidden">` (the hidden input component and the action listener will only set their value during update model values which is later than validations phase; the attribute tag has better to be set on the component which invokes the validator). As the functional requirement is unclear, it's not possible to suggest the best alternative.

---

**Update** as per the comments, apparently all you need to know is if the particular button is pressed or not; in that case just give it and the parent form a fixed ID

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton id="send" ...>
```

this way it will have a fixed request parameter name of `form:send` and you could check on that in the validator:

```
if (externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().containsKey("form:send")) {
    // Send button is pressed.
}
```

You can by the way also check for that in the `required` validators as follows:

```
<h:inputText ... required="#{not empty param['form:send']}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Action dependent requireness](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/action-dependent-requireness.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your hint. But when I use one of those alternatives, do I have the parameter's value already when the validators are called?

Comment: The `<input type="hidden">` is most likely your best bet.

Comment: But I need a value that's only set when I invoke the `h:commandButton`. And it should be present already at the validation phase. As you've written a hidden `input` couldn't do that. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Aha, in this particular case, just check if the button is pressed by checking its parameter name. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've tried your code but unfortunately `form:send` isn't included in the map. Instead it's `_jbpns_2fdefault_PortletName_PortletNoSecurityWindowsnpbj:j_id59:suche:suchTypButton`. I'd now iterate through all items and check if one of them ends with `form:send`. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Ah well. As an alternative you could consider to use `h:commandLink` and throw in some CSS to make it look like a button. Or you could use JavaScript on click to set a hidden input field value.